# What does boop/boope means? (Is it a valid word)

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, dictionaries

I didn't find this word: **boop/boope** in dictionary. But I heard it many times in life.

I want to know the meaning of this word and can this word be used in a "cute" context? I want to buy a domain with some "cute" word in it and so I am preparing the list of words that can be used.

Secondly, it is possible that this might be an invalid word because maybe I don't remember it correctly.

Comment: Please cite the usage.

Comment: you heard it many time in what context?  what do you think it means?

Comment: https://www.picturescafe.com/betty-boop

Comment: Noses seem to be involved, perhaps. [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boop).

Comment: urban dictionary has a definition ... you can answer your own question.

Comment: @lbf I don't correctly remember where I heard it, but probably in my childhood watching some movie or playing video game.

Comment: @WeatherVane The usage is I want to buy domain based on some "cute" word. So I was trying to find multiple words that might fit this criteria.

Comment: Please improve your question by editing it.

Comment: @lbf Maybe Im remembering it wrong Im not sure. And yes I saw it too on urban dictionary but it is only place where this word is listed, can I rely on it's meaning?

Comment: Please stop contradicting yourself.

Comment: yes i believe you can ... but others may disagree.  we shall see.

Comment: @lbf thanks, lets see if anyone else has insight on this word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The mystery of the boop shall never be revealed. But when saying
>   "**Boop**" you must poke a random person on the nose. [urban
>   dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=boop)

Why not in 'standard dictionaries'?  That takes time ... time for the use of the word to fade away ... or enter the lexicon.  May Betty Boop knows. Finally I did not mention bronchiolitis obliterans organizing pneumonia (BOOP)!

see 8 or so definitions ... all refer to the nose of animals, man included.  You can see the 'votes' on each too. So boop to you!

Answer (score 2):

It's onomatopoeia, and yes could definitely be considered a 'cute' word (especially in the case of one 'booping' a puppy's nose, for example)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, to boop something is to lightly tap it on the nose.

Comment: This would be improved by including an authoritative definition.